# Extracting bits from boost multiprecision

Tags: c++, boost, biginteger

I'm using uint256_t to make arithmetic operation on big integers; I would like to extract the bits of the numbers in a regular form, (i.e. not in a floating point form) without any precision since I'm only using integers and not floats.

For example:
if my code has:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>    
uint256_t v = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff61;
```

Then I would like to have 32 bytes:

```
61 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the backend representation directly.

Check the documentation whether this is part of the public API.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f9c76157d654e3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    uint256_t v("0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff61");

    std::copy_n(v.backend().limbs(), v.backend().size(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<unsigned>(std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase, " "));
}
```

Prints

```
0xffffff61 0xffffffff
```

Drop `std::showbase` to do without `0x`. I picked this representation so it's maximally clear how the `limb`s are grouped.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have directly what you ask. Internal rapresentation is not necessarily done that way, one type uses even 'decimal' digits.

You can obtain that indirectly

```
uint256_t v = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff61;
std::ostringstream ost ;
ost << std::hex << v ;
```

now ost.str() is FFFF....FFF61

Comment: This is not a bad idea, although it has two issues: the initializer assumes the compiler has 128bit literal support. Second, "you cannot have directly what you ask" is a bit of a stretch. I haven't checked how much of the backend API is documented, but parts of it certainly are.